# Compiling new Android APIs for use in my application

Tags: android, api

To take a simple example [String.isEmpty()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29) was made available in API level 9.

If I wanted to use this method in my application that targets API levels less than 9, how would I go about this?

Is it as simple as locating the source code of this method and importing the class/method? - Perhaps renaming it with my own package name for reference?

Can I compile a separate jar of the new API classes that I wish to use?

Is this what the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) does for selected APIs?

Have I completely misunderstood some fundamental basics of the Android Framework? If I have, please be nice and perhaps offer me some links to reading material!

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374118/why-old-android-phone-cannot-run-new-api-app) asks a similar question, but the answer doesn't resolve all of the above for me.

I thank you in advance.

Comment: I've run into this a few times.  I've considered pulling the code from the Android source and putting it in my project, but it always seems to turn out that there's a good reason why it isn't in the support library (i.e. it relies on a huge new feature of the OS), and that same reason will probably keep you from backporting it also.

Comment: Thank you. From CommonsWare's answer below, I assume I'm safe with the above example, as it's trivial? - Whereas if I was looking to include APIs to do with offline-recognition for example, I know that they would of course fail. Does that pretty much cover what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.  I think the real trick is managing to encapsulate just the feature you want, without having to pull in some giant subsystem of the OS just to make it work.  In my opinion, if it was going to be an easy task and have a wide appeal, it'd already be in the support library (but maybe your target feature is easy but doesn't have the wide appeal...)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it as simple as locating the source code of this method and importing the class/method? - Perhaps renaming it with my own package name for reference?

For something as trivial as this, it is as simple as copying and pasting the implementation into some static method of your own somewhere. You have no means of changing the implementation of `String` on millions of devices, so you have no means of putting `isEmpty()` on `String` on API Level 8 or lower. But, you could create a `StringCompat` class with a static `isEmpty()` method that borrows from the implementation you see in the source code.

> Can I compile a separate jar of the new API classes that I wish to use?

That would depend upon what the "new API classes" are.

> Is this what the support library does for selected APIs?

Sort of. The Android Support package, in some cases, has other modifications to allow the code to work on older devices. For example, in the native API Level 11 implementation of fragments, fragments work with any `Activity`; in the Android Support package, fragments are tied to `FragmentActivity`.

Other pieces of code in the Android Support package might be direct clones of their native counterparts, except for package and/or class name changes.

Comment: Lightening response! Your answers all over Stackoverflow are always so knowledgeable and useful. Thank you.